# Divs in Table Cell force one line

Tags: html, css

I've the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    </head>
<body>

    <table style="margin: 250px; width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: Yellow; table-layout: fixed;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="margin: auto auto auto -50px; background-color: Green; width:100px; height:50px;">L</div>
                <div style="margin: auto -50px auto auto; background-color: Green; width:100px; height:50px;">R</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the green boxes with R & L to be on the same line w/o using JS, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add "float:left;" to the style attribute on the box L
and add "float:right;" to the style attribute on the box R

then add valign="top" at the td tag. The parent tag of the boxes if you want it align to the top.

see code below

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>

</head>
<body>

    <table style="margin: 250px; width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: Yellow; table-layout: fixed;">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <div style="float:left;margin: auto auto auto -50px; background-color: Green; width:100px; height:50px;">L</div>
                <div style="margin: auto -50px auto auto; background-color: Green; width:100px; height:50px;float:right;">R</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One thing I found when using float vertical alignment of the container somehow gets ignored always v-aligning to the top. Is there a way fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Add css style "`float:left;`". It will solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css `display: inline-block`. Note that this doesn't work in older browser versions.

Alternatively you can use `float: left`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="margin: auto auto auto -50px; background-color: Green; width:100px; height:50px; float:left;">L</div>
<div style="margin: auto -50px auto auto; background-color: Green; width:100px; height:50px; float:left;">R</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either add css `float: left` to DIV L only;

Or you can add css `float: left` to DIV L and `float: right` to DIV R.

Ultimately, it depends on what you are trying to achieve here.